# preserve unlimited pagination after entering it's item

Tags: jquery, angularjs, web, pagination

I'm trying to keep previously loaded items (a lot of items) in pagination which is like "LOAD MORE ELEMENTS" (accumulated feed).

Entering some item in this list will not return me back to this big bunch of items.

I referred lot of sites which implement this, but unable to do it.

Which is the best way to solve it using angular or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be by using sessionStorage. In sessionStorage you can store a session variable that keeps track of the number of visible items. Each time you click on 'load more elements' you'd increment the value of this variable. Upon returning to the initial page you can simply retrieve this variable to see how many items were previously opened and make this number of items visible.

You can also do the same for the scroll position if you like. This way you can return a person back to the exact state that the page was in when they left it.

Don't forget to reset these variables when visiting other pages that are not related to this list of items.